# How to access camera in iPhone and how can i save pictures to a custom photo album.?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new to `iOS` , I want to access camera to take pictures. And save those pictures into a custom photo Library.By googling I got that I want to use either `UIImagePickerController` or `AVFoundation` Framework.How can I access camera and save pictures into a custom photo library using `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: You dont want to store the photos in the iPhone's default photo library?

Comment: No, I want to save them in separate library.

Comment: First of all, you are required to try to make a project/application, and to put here an exact question about it, if you have problems with working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)camaraBtnPress:(id)sender
{
    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
}
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [imagePickerController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [imagePickerController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    //to save in library
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

And follow this [link](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/) to save photo in custom photo album

Comment: Your code is working fine. But I want to save the captured images into  a custom library.

Comment: hi..follow this link. this will helpful for you http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/